# Does every finitely presentable group have a presentation that simultaneously minimizes the number of generators and number of relators?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

This should probably be an easy question, but I don't know how to answer it: Suppose *G* is a finitely <strike>generated</strike> presentable group. Suppose *a* is the absolute minimum of the sizes of all generating sets for *G* and *b* is the absolute minimum of the number of relations over all presentations of *G*. Question: Is it necessary that *G* has a presentation that simultaneously has *a* generators and *b* relations?

The case *b = 0* is just the fact that a free group cannot be generated by fewer elements than its free rank.

The problem could probably be interpreted in terms of CW-complexes (where the generators give rise to 1-cells and the relators give rise to 2-cells) but, because of my lack of familiarity with CW-complexes, I don't immediately see how to use these to solve the problem.

It also seems to be related to the notion of "deficiency" of a group, which is the (maximum possible over all presentations) difference #generators - #relations (under the opposite sign convention, the minimum possible difference #relations - #generators).

Comment: As I remember, if a group $G$ has presentation with $k$ relations, then for any generating set with $n$ elements the number of relations is $\leq k+n$.  

Comment: I'd guess that the abelian case should be tractable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A stronger question, is the deficiency of $G$ realized for a presentation with
the minimal number of generators (rank($G$))? This question is asked in a [paper of Rapaport](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=308277), and proved to be true for nilpotent and 1-relator groups.

Addendum:

The question appears as Question 2, p. 2, of a [book by Gruenberg](http://books.google.com/books?id=1PQ1BVOl7WMC&lpg=PP7&ots=3Q_OnZqmeW&dq=gruenberg%2520relation%2520modules&lr&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q&f=false). Lubotzky
has answered the analogous question affirmatively in the category of profinite
groups ([Corollary 2.5](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1848964)). (Note though that this is in the category of profinite presentations, so it does not imply an affirmative answer even for finite groups).

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful and seems to answer my question (or rather, indicate what's known about the answer to the question).

Comment: This paraphrasing isn't immediately equivalent to the original question: why couldn't there be a group with rank 4 and 6 relations which admits a presentation with 6 generators and 7 relations that realizes deficiency bound? 

Comment: Yes Victor, the condition is only sufficient. I changed the wording. 

Comment: I think the 1-relator group case is almost trivial: a group with a presentation with $n$ generators and 1 relator can only be generated by less than $n$ elements if it's free. Also, the link to the Gruenberg book seems to be wrong (I don't know what book you're linking to; Relation Modules?)

Comment: Thanks Steve, I fixed the link. The 1-relator case is indeed trivial, but I was pointing out that it appears in the paper. 

Comment: Another reference is Chapter 12 in John Wilson's book Profinite Groups.

Comment: What's trivial about the statement that a one-relator group isn't generated by a smaller set?  A proof isn't at all obvious to me.

Comment: @Henry: I suppose I should have said "classical" instead of trivial. I think this follows from the fact that 1-relator presentations are aspherical, together with Stallings criterion for freeness. If $G$ had $n-1$ generators, then $H_1(G)=Z^n$, which implies that $H_2(G)=0$ by thinking about the presentation complex. Then Stallings says that $n-1$ generators would have to generate a free subgroup. 

Comment: Ian, I don't see how to apply Stallings in this case.  There are lots of interesting 2-dimensional groups with $H_2=0$ (eg Baumslag--Solitar groups).  This much is clear to me: if the smaller generating set comes with an aspherical presentation then calculating $H_2$ leads to a contradiction. But off the top of my head I don't see why that should be the case.

Comment: I had a typo, I meant $H_1(G)=Z^(n-1)$. Suppose $G$ had $n-1$ generators. Then Theorem 7.4 of http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=175956 implies that these $n-1$ generators generate a free group. 

Comment: Oh, right, *that* criterion for freeness.  My apologies, I was thinking of 'cohomological dimension 1'.  Thanks for the explanation, Ian.

Comment: @Agol: Wilson's book on pro-finite groups (page 242) says that this question is open for finite p-groups. Rapaport paper is dated 1973 and Wilson's book is dated 1997. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Benli: Wilson's book doesn't seem to cite Rapaport's paper (although I don't have a copy of the book - I just did a search using google books) so maybe Wilson didn't know of the result. 

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer, but merely an observation that there can be no computable procedure to transform any given finite presentation into a presentation that is optimal in your sense. The reason is that the problem of determining if a finitely presented group is nontrivial is not computably decidable, but it is computably decidable from any optimal presentation, since the trivial group and only the trivial group has a=b=0.

So an affirmative answer cannot proceed by modifying the given presentation in some computable manner.

Comment: Except for some classes of presentable groups which are decidable.

Comment: In fact, something even stronger follows, namely that you can't algorithmically minimise the number of generators.  (It's easy to check if a cyclic group is trivial!)

Comment: Yes, and you also can't computably minimize the number of relations, since it is easy to check if a free group is trivial.